# VAT-Id activated. missing field in shipping or billing address on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, address, vat

I've activated the option "Show Vat-Id in frontend" but the VAT-ID Field on the checkout page address forms is still not displayed.

How can i add the VAT-ID field to the address forms on the checkout page?